# Navigation similar to Gmail Android application

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android

> Note: I am using Xamarin - but will accept an answer in Java Android -

I have an android application in which I have similar navigation to the gmail android application.

I have a Left drawer navigation. With following Options

1. Assets (Like gmail application Inbox fragment) -

When user launches the application they are shown this fragment by default - When a user is on this Activity and presses the back button the Application should close

2. Geofences

When user is on this fragment and presses back it should go back to the Assets (Inbox) Fragment

3. Notifications

When user is on this fragment and presses back it should go back to the Assets (Inbox) Fragment

This is how I launch the Default Fragment in my Activity

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
 // Set the initial fragment i.e. AssetListFragment
 var fragment = new AssetListFragment();
 var ft = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
                        .Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment);

  ft.Commit();

}
```

And then when an item from the Drawer navigation is clicked I launch the fragment like the following:

```
    private void NavigationDrawerItemSelected(object sender, NavigationView.NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (e.MenuItem.ItemId)
        {
            case Resource.Id.nav_assets:
                fragment = new AssetListFragment();
                break;

            case Resource.Id.nav_geofences:
                fragment = new GeofenceFragment();
                break;

            case Resource.Id.nav_notifications:
                fragment = new NotificationsFragment();
                break;
        }


        if (fragment != null)
        {
            var fragmentName = fragment.GetType().Name;

            var fragmentPopped = SupportFragmentManager.PopBackStackImmediate(fragmentName, 0);

            if (!fragmentPopped)
            {
                var ft = SupportFragmentManager
                                .BeginTransaction()
                                .AddToBackStack(fragmentName)
                                .Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment);

                ft.Commit();
            }
        }

        // Close drawer
        _drawerLayout.CloseDrawers();
    }
```

When the user clicks the back button I have done the following:

```
    public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        if (_drawerLayout != null && _drawerLayout.IsDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.Start))
            _drawerLayout.CloseDrawers();
        else
        {
            if (SupportFragmentManager.BackStackEntryCount > 0)
                SupportFragmentManager.PopBackStackImmediate();
            else
                base.OnBackPressed();

        }

    }
```

What I need to do is always go back to the First Screen (in my case the AssetListFragment) (in gmail android app the Inbox Fragment)

How can I do this? Currently all the fragments loaded from the Navigation Draw are added to the stack, when I click on the Back button it goes to the previous fragment not the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You added the fragment to the stack, when you at the second or third fragment and press back button you should pop all the fragments out before the `AssetListFragment`

Android provide the API `PopBackStackImmediate(id,flag)` to navigate the target fragment.

In my example the `FragmentOne` is the first fragment like `AssetListFragment` :

```
if (FragmentManager.BackStackEntryCount > 0)
{
    FragmentManager.PopBackStackImmediate(new FragmentOne().Id, PopBackStackFlags.None);
}
else
{
    base.OnBackPressed();
}
```

**Edit**

For your requirement in the stack the fragment should be store as 1->2->3->1 and we when we find the current fragment is 1 and click back button should close app:

Android does not provide the API to detect the current fragment we can add a static Arraylist to store the fragments you added.

`public static ArrayList myFragments = new ArrayList();`

Add every fragment you replaced to the list :

```
 private void Bt1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FragmentThree fThree = new FragmentThree();
            FragmentManager fm = FragmentManager;
            FragmentTransaction tx = fm.BeginTransaction();
            //tx.Hide(this);
            //tx.Add(Resource.Id.frameLayout1, fThree, "THREE");
            MainActivity.myFragments.Add(fThree);
            tx.Replace(Resource.Id.frameLayout1, fThree, "THREE");  
            tx.AddToBackStack(null);
            tx.Commit();
        }
```

Check the current fragment if it is the FragmentOne :

```
Fragment lastFragment = (Fragment)(myFragments[myFragments.Count - 1]);


            if (lastFragment.Tag.Equals("ONE"))
            {
                myFragments.Clear();
                Finish();

            }
            else
            {
                if (FragmentManager.BackStackEntryCount > 0)
                {

                    FragmentManager.PopBackStackImmediate(new FragmentOne().Id, PopBackStackFlags.None);
                    myFragments.RemoveRange(1, myFragments.Count-1);
                }

                else
                {
                    base.OnBackPressed();
                }
            }
```

[image]

As another workaround, when you press back button just replace the current fragment with the `AssetListFragment`:

```
   public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        if (_drawerLayout != null && _drawerLayout.IsDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.Start))
            _drawerLayout.CloseDrawers();
        else if(FragmentManager.BackStackEntryCount > 1)
        {
            Fragment fragment = new AssetListFragment();
            var ft = SupportFragmentManager
                        .BeginTransaction()
                        .AddToBackStack(null)
                        .Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment);
            ft.Commit();
        }
        else
        {
             base.OnBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If we go from Fragment 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1 by navigation drawer (don't click back), then when on fragment 1 click on the back button this will keep the app open - but if a user is on fragment 1 - it should always close the App

Comment: @DawoodAwan "but if a user is on fragment 1"  I am not understand this sentence, the user should on fragment 1 and click the back button keep the app open. you can try the code I have edited just now. If the first 1 fragment is there I think you can go back to 1. If not I think you can go to 2.

Comment: if user is on fragment 1 it should always close the application - if user is on 2 or 3 it should always go back to 1